# Alternate <div> Visibility (mouseover image)

Tags: css, image, html, hover

I'm having some trouble here. I want to show an image when mouse is hovered above following div.

HTML:

```
<div id="testmouseover">
<img src="testmouseover.png">
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#testmouseover 
{ 
     left: -9px; 
     top: -9px; 
     position: absolute; 
     width: 865px;
     height: 653px;
     z-index:1;
}
```

I have 4 of these divs wich should display a different image, so how can I add an ID to the hover?
Can someone help me with writing the CSS code for the hover? It will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Have an `onmouseover()` event attached to the div. You can take some pointers from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp).

In the function that is being called at onmouseover, change the `innerHTML` property to have the desired image.

This can be achieved even quicker using jQuery:

```
$("#divId").click(function(){
    $(this).html("Ur image html here")
});
```

Comment: Much too complicated and your answer requires including jQuery. Simply using your code will not work. See my answer for an incredibly simple and pure CSS solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22748599/3461722

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier than you think: try #testmouseover:hover

If that's not the right answer, please share a code sample on codepen

Answer (score 0):

Here is an html version if it helps. The z-index is for layering images (stacking) not for mouse overs if I am correct.

```
<img src="NORMAL IMAGE" onmouseover="this.src='MOUSE OVER IMAGE'" onmouseout="this.src='Normal Image'" alt="ALTERNET TEXT">
```

Comment: If You only need it on the one page my answer will work, but if You need it for more than one page, a pure CSS methode will be needed.  It would help if You could clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, pure CSS:

```css
#testmouseover img {
    display: none;
}
#testmouseover:hover img {
    display: inline;
}
```

Be sure to give the div some width and height so that you don't get weird flickering stuff. For multiple divs just give them different IDs and copy this CSS a few times. If all the divs are the same you could also give them all the same class, or give them a class with the above mentioned CSS and an ID with the div specific styles.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/S44MS/